Form validation JavaScript unresponsive to "submit" eventListener
I've been assigned a task to make a sign-up page for a hypothetical training business.
I'm currently creating the form validation for the first name input, which checks whether the field is empty, equal to the placeholder, has any numbers or special characters. However, my code is not responding when I click my button element (not input type=submit).
The expected result was the font colour to change to pink and the innerText to display "Please enter a valid first name".
I've attempted calling both the form form.addEventListener("submit", newCustomer); and the button btn.addEventListener("submit", newCustomer); in my JavaScript, but nothing happens.


var fname = document.getElementById("f-name");
var lname = document.getElementById("l-name");
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var card = document.getElementById("card");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const form = document.getElementById("form");

var Customers = [];

function newCustomer(event, firstname, lastname, emailAddress, cardNum) {
  event.preventDefault();
  firstname = fname;
  lastname = lname;
  emailAddress = email;
  cardNum = card;

  if (firstname === "" || firstname.placeholder === "Enter Your Firstname") {
    firstname.innerText = "Please enter a valid first name";
    firstname.style.color = "rgb(231,0,100)";
  } else {
    var specialChars = /[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]/g;
    for (let i = 0; i < firstname.value.length - 1; i++) {
      if (!isNaN(firstname[i])) {
        firstname.style.color = "rgb(231,0,100)";
        firstname.innerText = "Please enter a valid first name";
      } else if (specialChars.test(firstname[i]) == true) {
        firstname.style.color = "rgb(231,0,100)";
        firstname.innerText = "Please enter a valid first name";
      } else {
        firstname.style.color = "rgb(137,200,46)";
        form.reset();
      }
    }
  }
}
btn.addEventListener("submit", newCustomer)
<div class="form-container">
  <form action="" id="form">
    <div class="form-top">
      <div class="title">
        <label for="firstname" class="firstname">First Name:</label>
        <label for="lastname" class="lastname">Last Name:</label>
        <label for="email address" class="email-address">Email:</label>
        <label for="card details " class="card-details"> Card:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="textbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Firstname" id="f-name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" id="l-name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="email">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number" id="card">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container"><button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
  </form>

</div>




Attach the event to the form (then your code is executed), you're submitting the form, not the button.

@Teemu Thanks, I also had another quick question. When the javascript is run it only turns the input pink. The form doesn't seem to respond to the first if clause, nor does the form display the innerText for the rest of them when submitted. Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

@YolandaOnyenze: This is a good opportunity to start using your browser’s debugging tools.  With the script debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe what each individual operation does.  This will help you narrow down why something is happening.

I have the following comments and an example.

The submit event is fired on the form. In the following example the submit call back function is only used for (in this case) adding data to the array.
Use the build-in form validation. Instead of using the submit call back for validation set the required attribute on the required form fields. Here I use the pattern attribute to validate the first name, but there are also other attributes for validation. The form will only submit if the form validates.
Use the name attribute on input elements. The name attribute is used as the key for form field. Avoid hyphen (-) in the value of  the name attribute. Then you can use the dot-syntax like mentioned here ↴
Reduce the number of global variables. In this case where you have a form you can just use the name attribute for getting an element (like, form.fname).
Keep the label and the input element together. Then you don't need an id on the input element.
General: Don't repeat yourself -- only write the same code once.



const form01 = document.forms.form01;
var Customers = [];

function newCustomer(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let form = event.target;
  let data = new FormData(form);
  Customers.push(Object.fromEntries(data));
  form.reset();
}

function onInvalid(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.target.classList.add('invalid');
}

function onInput(event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valid) {
    event.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
}

form01.addEventListener("submit", newCustomer);
form01.addEventListener("invalid", onInvalid, true);
form01.addEventListener("input", onInput, true);
.form-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.feedback {
  display: none;
  color: rgb(231, 0, 100);
}

.invalid~.feedback {
  display: inline;
}
<div class="form-container">
  <form action="" name="form01">
    <div class="form-top">
      <label>First Name:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Firstname"
          name="f-name" pattern="[a-zA-ZáÁãÃöÖ\-]{2,100}" required>
        <span class="feedback">Please enter a valid first name</span>
      </label>
      <label>Last Name:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" name="l-name">
      </label>
      <label>Email:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email" name="email">
      </label>
      <label>Card:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number" name="card">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container"><button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
  </form>
</div>




Thank you, this is very helpful and informative!
